# Trade ETFs with Banks' Brokerages or separate Discount Brokerage?

Tags: canada, brokerage, online-brokerage

Hereafter, all money is in Canadian Dollars. My relative in Canada banks with HSBC Canada, is an Advanced customer, and possesses an HSBC InvestDirect account.
She buys and holds for the long run,
around $2000  of only ETFs, monthly or every two months.

Should she trade using HSBC InvestDirect, or try another brokerage? Because of HSBC's costlier transaction fees, she could reduce her rate of purchase (ie every 2 months instead of every month). She could try [another brokerage](http://www.moneysense.ca/invest/canadas-best-discount-brokerages-2014/), but she worries about bank transfer charges. She is happy with a discount brokerage; she doesn't need a brokerage with a physical location.

Comment: Requests for specific product/service recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea I meant to ask in general, whether the conditions above suggest changing to some other brokerage. I wasn't seeking recommendations of a brokerage.

Comment: Doesn't your link to a list of discount brokerage already supply you with the information you need to decide, if this is strictly a cost optimization problem? If not, what are you asking? Any legitimate discount broker will take your ETF order and charge their stipulated commissions/fees. What other issues might concern you?

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea Re your 1st question: No, because other reasons may exist for switching or staying. I'm asking in general whether one should stay with one's bank's brokerages, or switch to a lesser known one. Does this help?

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to generalize it better, then, because it didn't read that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at HSBCs [website](http://www.hsbc.com.tr/advance/eng/faster-access-more-control.asp), it looks like advanced customers are allowed free fund tranfers out of their checking/saving account. I would call the bank to guarantee that the transfers don't face a .5% fee for any outgoing transfer to another brokerage, as listed on this [site](http://www.hsbc.com.tr/eng/retail_banking/interest_rates_and_fees/fees.asp#4). However, given that trades are as low as [$6.88](http://www.hsbc.ca/1/2/personal/investing/products-and-services/self-directed-investing/rates-commissions), I'm not sure she could save much by switching to another brokerage.

Comment: Is that HSBC Canada's website?

Comment: Yep, I noticed. I just fixed it for the Canadian site.

Comment: That's wrong.  [It's a flat $135 transfer out fee and will most likely be refunded by the receiving institution.](http://www.hsbc.ca/1/2/personal/investing/products-and-services/self-directed-investing/rates-commissions/administration-fees) .  Given the commissions are only $7-$10, there may not be any savings elsewhere.

Comment: @brian, thanks. I included that information and updated the answer.

Comment: @Bishop Sorry, but your link isn't to HSBC Canada?

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit HSBC's website is hard to navigate to find the correct information. There appears to be different practices between accounts types, as well as countries. I think the best idea is for her to call the bank and find out how much it would cost to transfer funds to another brokerage, and use that information to compare the two options.